# Android app custom keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I want to make a lock page for my app which should have lock screen with custom keyboard (not soft keyboard) like that in Moto G.

Any pointers in this regards would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried to do it ?

Comment: custom keyboear mean if you want keyboard like pin login, in which you will have only digits. i can send you.

Comment: https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't want to use the 'keyboard' which android provide, if so you can just

1. place some buttons on your layut
2. place labels on each buttons
3. make that buttons to commit texts what you want to commit for each buttons